# Document link within page - Open in officewebapps

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, office-web-apps

Does anyone know if it's possible to link to a document within a content editor web part and force it to open in Office Web Apps? A lot of my users make content just within pages as they don't need a full document library but want to link the occasional document that I'd rather used OWA than forcing the user to open/download.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question on this one.

Open the document in office web apps and the url will look like

```
https://officewebapps/Societies/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=/Societies/Documents/Application%20form.docx&action=default
```

Using the power of imagination you can work out from the link of a doc how to force it to open in web apps.